# Why do python dictionaries change order?

Tags: python, dictionary

The order of objects stored in dictionaries in python3.5 changes over different executions of the interpreter, but it seems to stay the same for the same interpreter instance.

```
$ python3 <(printf 'print({"a": 1, "b": 2})\nprint({"a": 1, "b": 2})\nprint({"a": 1, "b": 2})\nprint({"a": 1, "b": 2})')
{'b': 2, 'a': 1}
{'b': 2, 'a': 1}
{'b': 2, 'a': 1}
{'b': 2, 'a': 1}
$ python3 <(printf 'print({"a": 1, "b": 2})\nprint({"a": 1, "b": 2})\nprint({"a": 1, "b": 2})\nprint({"a": 1, "b": 2})')
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

I always thought the order was based off of the hash of the key. Why is the order different between different executions of python?

Comment: It does look like the answer to this question is buried as an aside in the accepted answer there, but I don't think the questions are asking the same thing.

Comment: yes, maybe you're right. So I'm undeleting my previous answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionaries use `hash` function, and the order *is* based on the hash of the key all right.

But, as stated somewhere in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479928/why-is-the-order-in-dictionaries-and-sets-arbitrary), starting from python 3.3, the seed of the hash is randomly chosen at execution time (not to mention that it depends on the python versions) .

> Note that as of Python 3.3, a random hash seed is used as well, making hash collisions unpredictable to prevent certain types of denial of service (where an attacker renders a Python server unresponsive by causing mass hash collisions). This means that the order of a given dictionary is then also dependent on the random hash seed for the current Python invocation.

So each time you execute your program, you may get a different order.

Since order of dictionaries are not guaranteed (not before python 3.6 anyway), this is an implementation detail that you shouldn't consider.

Answer (score -2):

dictionaries are inherently unordered. expecting any standardized behavior of the "order" is not realistic.

to keep the ordering, make an ordered list of .keys()

Comment: that's not the question.

Comment: Also, you'd want to use OrderedDict (from the collections module)